# How do I host static files in WSO2 Carbon 3.2.2?

Tags: wso2

I have installed WSO2 Carbon 3.2.2 and would like to host some static files that I can access from a browser (specifically, a variety of HTML and JavaScript files that make up a working website).  I want to be able to access the files from `http://localhost:9763/<MY_FILES>`.  With Carbon 3.0.0 this was as simple as putting the files in `<CARBON_HOME>/webapps/`.  Carbon 3.2.2 does not have the `<CARBON_HOME>/webapps/` directory, and adding it doesn't help.

I noticed that (after installing certain features) there is another webapps directory located `<CARBON_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/`, but that appears to be specifically for deploying war files.

I've tried putting my files everywhere I can think of, but I've had no luck.

Is there a feature that I have to install?  Is there a special location to put these files?  Is this still a supported feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is never been an advertised feature of Carbon nor it has been recommended. Hence you can't expect to have backward compatibility for a "non feature".

The right thing to in a production environment is to use a web server (Apache, nginx etc...) to serve static files because web servers are optimized to do that. Then proxy the connections to Carbon via the web server. For example, by using mod_proxy for Apache.

You can still use the Application Server (or after installing AppServer features into any Carbon server) to create a .war file and have your static site there. Then again if it's a static site using Application Server is an overkill.

Comment: Consider this: I have a SOAP or REST based javascript client that runs in the web browser. If the JS file is served from a web server on port 80, it can not communicate with an application served from WSAS on port 8080 since that breaks same origin policy. By removing the static file undocumented feature, ws02 has just made itself less relevent: only works with web browsers using the patterns os jsp style approach. Thats a shame. I am going to give you the bounty because you answered the question, but I think that ws02 is really missing the boat these days...

Comment: Shane, when you configure mod_proxy you can configure in such a manner say, you host your JS client on port 80. So your JS is accessible like http://example.com/myfile.js. Then say your WSAS is running on port 8080 and is accessible from http://example.com:8080. When you configure mod_proxy you can configure in such a manner that http://example.com/wsas -> http://example.com:8080. So to your JS file it will appear as coming from the same domain. Also there's another project that you might be interested in - http://jaggeryjs.org. It's a complete JS based webapp dev framework, JS on server side.

Comment: Understood Chintana, however, this is an additional service I did not have to start up before just to serve a couple of JS and HTML files. As for Jaggery, doesnt help us with SOAP services does it?

Comment: Shane, if you download the latest version (currently 5.0.1) of Application Server - http://wso2.com/products/application-server/ it ships Jaggery components as well as Mashup components. With Mashups you can expose a SOAP service using Javascript.